# Input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //read in the file
    StreamReader convert = new StreamReader("../../convert.txt");

    //define variables
    string line = convert.ReadLine();
    int conversion;
    int numberIn;
    float conversionFactor;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the conversion in the form (amount,from,to)");
    String inputMeasurement = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] inputMeasurementArray = inputMeasurement.Split(',');

    while (line != null)
    {
        string[] fileMeasurementArray = line.Split(',');
        if (fileMeasurementArray[0] == inputMeasurementArray[1])
        {
            if (fileMeasurementArray[1] == inputMeasurementArray[2])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileMeasurementArray[2]);
            }
        }

        line = convert.ReadLine();

        //convert to int
        numberIn = Convert.ToInt32(inputMeasurementArray[0]);
        conversionFactor = Convert.ToInt32(fileMeasurementArray[2]);

        conversion = (numberIn * conversionFactor);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

On the line `conversionFactor = Convert.ToInt32(fileMeasurementArray[2]);`, I am getting an error saying "Input string was not in correct format". Please help!

The text file consists of the following:

```
ounce,gram,28.0
pound,ounce,16.0
pound,kilogram,0.454
pint,litre,0.568
inch,centimetre,2.5
mile,inch,63360.0
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention what you entered via console. Was there an exception thrown? It looks like that argument to Convert.ToInt32 is not valid integer represented in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert a float to an int.

Define conversionFactor as a double

also the variable conversion needs to be a double aswell.

like so

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.IO;

namespace measurementConverter { 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {  //read in the file 
            StreamReader convert = new StreamReader("../../convert.txt");

            //define variables
            string line = convert.ReadLine();
            double conversion;
            int numberIn;
            double conversionFactor;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the conversion in the form (amount,from,to)");
            String inputMeasurement = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] inputMeasurementArray = inputMeasurement.Split(',');

            while (line != null)
            {
                string[] fileMeasurementArray = line.Split(',');
                if (fileMeasurementArray[0] == inputMeasurementArray[1])
                {
                    if (fileMeasurementArray[1] == inputMeasurementArray[2])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", fileMeasurementArray[2]);
                    }
                }

                line = convert.ReadLine();

                //convert to int
                numberIn = Convert.ToInt32(inputMeasurementArray[0]);
                conversionFactor = Convert.ToDouble(fileMeasurementArray[2]);

                conversion = (numberIn * conversionFactor);
            }



            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accept it as the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the line of the text file, `fileMeasurementArray[2]` will be `28.0 pound`. This cannot be converted to an int. You should remove the string and keep only the number `28.0`.

**UPDATE**: the question was updated and the line of text file corrected. So my previous answer does'nt make sense anymore.

The problem occurs probably because you are trying to convert a float to an int.

Answer (score 0):

'28.0 pound' isn't an integer. I'd imagine that's where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

`numberIn` and `conversionFactor` are floats, not Ints. Use:

```
float numberIn;
float conversionFactor;
...

//convert to float
numberIn = Convert.ToSingle(inputMeasurementArray[0]);
conversionFactor = Convert.ToSingle(fileMeasurementArray[2]);
```